# Отслеживание имитированных нажатий на клавиатуру

Tags: python, клавиатура

```
keyboard.hook(lambda x: print('smth'))
keyboard.press('q')
```

После выполнения данного кода, ничего не выводится, хотя кнопка была "как бы" нажата. Выводится только если я реально нажимаю на клавиши. Возможно ли с этой библиотекой реализовать это?

Comment: Метод `keyboard.hook` не ловит свои же нажатия, хотя `keyboard.press('q')` сработал, верно?

Comment: Он работает, но при этом не ловит его

Comment: При этом совершенно, вроде как, аналогичная библиотека mouse работает так, как надо. Не знаю, то ли это баг такой, то ли так задумано